# What does this paragraph mean in Wasabi's "Japanese Adjectives with Particle が" article?

Tags: conjugations, adjectives, i-adjectives, na-adjectives

I'm trying to understand [this post](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/japanese-adjectives-with-particle-ga/) on using Japanese adjectives and am stumped by this paragraph under the I-adjectives section

> When you use i-adjectives as a subject complement, you MUST NOT do the same thing you do with na-adjectives. The variety of form is called “conjugation.” Using conjugation in place is significantly important when learning Japanese.

I have absolutely no clue what it is referring to by 'the same thing' and would appreciate any explanations

Comment: It must be referring to this earlier statement about na-adjectives: *When you use a na-adjective as a subject complement, it will work in the same way as Japanese nouns.* Isn’t it just saying i-adjectives don’t work like that and you have to change their forms?

Comment: I think the writer might not be a native speaker of English, because it's definitely an awkward paragraph.

Comment: I agree the paragraph is slightly awkward. aguijonazo your response makes sense, I think I will assume that's what they meant until I study them again in the future in more depth
Thank you